# How to scale background image to cover MainWindow in PyQt5

Tags: qt5, pyqt5, python-3.5

I trying to learn PyQt5 so it might a noobie question, but I search a lot and I couldn't find a solution. 
I wrinting a sample code showing a countdow to a defined datetime and now it looks like in the image below: 
[image: Current GUI]
I need to resize the image to **cover** the app, atm I have a window 300x200 and background image 2400x1800.
I also need the background to resize on MainWindow resize. At first glance css property **background-size** is not supported, border-image would strech the image.
OS: Windows 7-10 (not a choise)
Python: 3.4.3
PyQt: 5.5

***Current code (not working)***

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QTimer
import design
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# UI base class is inherited from design.Ui_MainWindow
class Counter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # applying background image
        self.background = QtGui.QPixmap("./assets/img/trecime.jpg")
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background,QtGui.QBrush(self.background).scale(self.size()))
        self.MainWindow.setPalette(palette)

        # custom colors for QLCDWidgets
        lcdPalette = self.dayCount.palette()
        lcdPalette.setColor(lcdPalette.WindowText, QtGui.QColor(255,0,0, 200))
        lcdPalette.setColor(lcdPalette.Background, QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))
        lcdPalette.setColor(lcdPalette.Light, QtGui.QColor(200, 0, 0, 120))
        lcdPalette.setColor(lcdPalette.Dark, QtGui.QColor(100, 0, 0, 150))
        self.dayCount.setPalette(lcdPalette)
        lcdPalette.setColor(lcdPalette.WindowText, QtGui.QColor(255,255,255, 200))
        lcdPalette.setColor(lcdPalette.Light, QtGui.QColor(200, 0, 0, 0))
        lcdPalette.setColor(lcdPalette.Dark, QtGui.QColor(200, 0, 0, 0))
        self.timeCount.setPalette(lcdPalette)

        # init Qtimer
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_timer)
        self.timer.start(200)

        # config final date
        self.finalDatetime = datetime(2016, 11, 30, 14, 00)

    def resizeEvent(self, resizeEvent):
        print('resized')

    def update_timer(self):
        currentDatetime = datetime.today()
        delta = self.finalDatetime -  currentDatetime
        (days, hours, minutes) = days_hours_minutes(delta)
        self.dayCount.display(days)
        # blinking colon
        separator = ":" if delta.microseconds < 799999 else ' '
        self.timeCount.display('%02d%s%02d' % (hours, separator, minutes))

def days_hours_minutes(td):
    return td.days, td.seconds//3600, (td.seconds//60)%60

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    counter = Counter()
    counter.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Publish the module `design.py`

Answer (score 1):

pyqt style sheet can be used for this resizing

try

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

  class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,MainWindow):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.start_button.setObjectName("start_button")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        self.stop_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.stop_button.setObjectName("stop_button")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.stop_button)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 26))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)






    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.start_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.stop_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))


stylesheet = """
        MainWindow {
        border-image: url("The_Project_logo.png"); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-position: center;
    }
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)  # <---
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(640, 640)
    window.show()


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```